# Getting data from json once and use it in 3 fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, pass-data

I am getting the data from `JSON` using volley, there is 3 `Fragment` in `Activity` which I have to populate these fragments with the data that I have received from `JSON` in `MainActivity`. I would like to get data from `JSON` once and use it in `Activity` and in all those 3 `Fragment`. I put the received data in a `List` like this:

```
List<Display_Activity_Model> videoDetailList;
```

and I send this list from activity to other fragments using an Interface like:

In activity I have this method:

```
@Override
public List<Display_Activity_Model> getDataList() {
    return videoDetailList;
}
```

In one of fragments I have:

```
public interface GetDataInterface {
    List<Display_Activity_Model> getDataList();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        sGetDataInterface= (GetDataInterface) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement GetDataInterface Interface");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(sGetDataInterface != null){
        dataListFromDispAct = sGetDataInterface.getDataList();
    }
}
```

When I debug the code, I see that the method `getDataList` in `MainActivity` is called before the method for fetching json with volley. So all the time I receive empty list.

My question is that: What is the best way to fetch data with volley once and use it in other fragments?

Update1:

@Keita Junichiro:

I defined "update" method in **fragment** like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_info,container,false);

    initComponents(view);

   if (dataListFromDispAct != null) {
        txt_view_count.setText(dataListFromDispAct.get(0).getView_count());
    }

    return view;
}

public void update(List<Display_Activity_Model> videoDetailList){

    dataListFromDispAct=videoDetailList;

}
```

and I am calling "update" method in **activity** after json loaded in "getItemMenuGson" method:

```
getItemMenuGson(new CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Display_Activity_Model> itemMenuGsonList) {
            videoDetailList=itemMenuGsonList;
            new Video_Info().update(videoDetailList);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String msg) {

        }
    });
```

The problem is method "onCreateView" in fragment is called before update method. When I declare update method static it is also the same and variable "dataListFromDispAct" is null all the time.

Update2:

[image: Debugging result]

Update 3:
@Piyush

I implemented your respond, but it is not working in this problem. I am getting empty list because method onCreateView executing earlier than getItemMenuGson method in Activity. I declared :

```
SharedApplication mapp = SharedApplication.getInstance();
ArrayList<String> myList = mapp.getArrayListData();
```

in onActivityCreated in fragment but it is also running before getItemMenuGson method in Activity. The order in which methods are calling:

[image: method's running order]

what should I do? How can I call getItemMenuGson method in Activity to fetch JSON and then load fragment layout to populate those loaded data to the fragment?

**Solution**: The key for the problem was **Static method** which runs first:

Define below codes in **Fragment**:

```
public class Video_Info extends Fragment {

static TextView txt_view_count;
List<Display_Activity_Model> dataListFromDispAct;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_info,container,false);
    txt_view_count= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_count);
    return view;
  }
public static void update(List<Display_Activity_Model> videoDetailList)
  {
    txt_view_count.setText(videoDetailList.get(0).getView_count());
  }
 }
```

In **Activity** after fetching data from JSON to list call update method:

```
 getItemMenuGson(new CallBack() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Display_Activity_Model> itemMenuGsonList) {
        videoDetailList = itemMenuGsonList;

         //////////////////
        Video_Info.update(videoDetailList);
        ///////////////////

        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(itemMenuGsonList.get(0).getMedia().getURL());
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

    }
```

Comment: Implement `Getter-Setter` methiod in `Application` singletone class for arraylist and set your arraylist in main activity after parsing. After that in each fragment you can access it through the singletone class.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a little bit?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know

Comment: Okay try and let me know. It will be worked.

Comment: Why don't use EventBus?

Comment: EventBus, I don't know what they are, let me search!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send data from activity to fragment after call API, you can create a method update() in fragment to receive data and call fragment.update() in activity when loadData finish().

```
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //Parse resonse to *videoDetailList*
        fragment.update(videoDetailList);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can modify method update, check fragment isVisible and set value for txt_view_count: if (isVisible() && videoDetailList != null && videoDetailList.size() > 0){txt_view_count.setText(dataListFromDispAct.get(0).getView_count());}

Comment: It is not working, the view is there, but isVisible() is all the time false, I changed the code inside update to if (videoDetailList != null && videoDetailList.size() > 0)
        {
            txt_view_count.setText(dataListFromDispAct.get(0).getView_count());
        } and the condition become true but the app crashed. I think we can't use  "txt_view_count.setText()" outside onCreateView. I also tested this txt_view_count.setText("2"); again crashed.

Comment: initComponents(view); working properly? can you check  txt_view_count == null after initComponents(view);? If fragment.isVisible(), then onCreateView has invoked, so that txt_view_count is not null.

Answer (score 0):

First make one singletone application class

```
public class SharedApplication extends Application{

ArrayList<String> arraylist;

public static SharedApplication instance=null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

public static SharedApplication getInstance()
{
    if(instance==null)
    {
        instance=new SharedApplication();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setArrayListData(ArrayList<String> setData)
{
    arraylist=setData;
}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayListData()
{
    return arraylist;

}

}
```

Now in your activity initialize your application class using

```
SharedApplication mApp; // declare global
```

initialize in onCreate() method

```
mApp = SharedApplication.getInstance();
```

Now after parse your data from server set data in arraylist

```
mApp.setArrayListData(yourArrayList);
```

Now whenever you want to get data any of fragment you should same initialize your application class in each fragment in which u want to get arraylist.

Like,

```
SharedApplication mapp = SharedApplication.getInstance();
ArrayList<String> myList = mapp.getArrayListData();
```

**Note :** You must add `SharedApplication` class in your manifest to `application` tag

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface with a method `onDownloadComplete`.

```
public interface DelegateClass {
    public static onDownloadComplete(String jsonData);
}
```

Now fetch data with Volley in `Activity` and call this method. Implement this interface in all your fragments and override `onDownloadComplete`. This method will be called when your `Activity` finishes fetching data. Like

```
public class YourFragment implements DelegateClass {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public static onDownloadComplete(String jsonData){
        //do what you want with data
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: you are saying: "Now fetch data with Volley in fragment" should I fetch in Fragment or Activity?