# Fetching data form JSON to a list in Activity and then pass list to 3 fragment in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-json

I have an `Activity`, and three tab each with it's own `Fragment`s. I am loading video information from JSON into a list in `Activity`.

I read URL of video from list and display it in upper half of `Activity` layout, I have three `Fragment`s in bottom half, the first `Fragment` shows info about video, second, related video, and third comments.

**Problem is:** I want to send the list from `Activity` to 3 `Fragments` in tabs.

I did lots of ways, using interfaces, callback,... but before fetching JSON data from url, `Fragments` starts and when this happens the empty list want to be set to `TextView`s, `EditText`s, `ImageView`s,... in `Fragment` and then application stops.

How to get data from JSON and then load `Fragments`? Or 
How to simultaneously load data to `Activity` itself and all `Fragments`?  Or
I can fetch that JSON in activity and 3 `Fragments` separately, but I don't want to do that!

Please give me a tutorial or an article to learn this subject.

Comment: Please show how you tried it..:)

Comment: provide some code please. we need the activity code and the web call code at least

Comment: Your question seem broad. Please shorten it and post LogCat in case of crash. Please also see - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630216/getting-data-from-json-once-and-use-it-in-3-fragment/39634164?noredirect=1#comment66600074_39634164

Comment: @Patzu why would you duplicate your own question?

Comment: I'll delete after finding an answer.

Comment: @Patzu this isn't how StackOverflow works. If your question isn't getting much attention, improve it and it will get bumped. This way it will only get downvotes and get closed.

Comment: sure, apology for duplicating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register callback listeners in your fragments.

Load JSON data in your activity and set the corresponding data to static variables.

Now trigger callback listeners in fragments when you set values in static variables after parsing JSON.

In your callback methods in fragments set the data from static variables.

Update:

You can also pass your data in callback listeners methods to fragments instead of using static variable.

Comment: I did use this approach, I couldn't set for example a TextView with static variable while fragment was loading.

Comment: you mean your data is loaded before fragments is loaded?

Comment: Yes, it worked! thanks. I will put then complete answer here.

Comment: this good if it solves your problem, you should accept this answer.

Comment: Using static data is not a good approach as this may lead to memory issues. While this may seem easy approach but this certainly is not correct. You should try using interface or an event bus as mentioned in example below.

Answer (score 2):

The best approch is to achieve it through interface and put extra but if some how you are not succed you can use below methods:

1.You can use **event bus** for integrating this funtionality

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

2. secondly you can do this by creating public **getter setter method** on parent   activity and calling them on fragment by parent activity type context/object.